# trim last ip octet and reverse

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am looking for a one liner solution that remove the last octet of an ip address and reverse the ip.

For e.g

`206.195.152.176` should become `152.195.206`

I am having trouble with the reverse part 
Below is the trim part

```
 echo 206.195.152.176 | sed 's/\.[0-9]*$//'
```

Comment: The correct answer to this will depend on how that IP address is stored. If it's in a file then `sed` or `awk` is the right approach but if its in a variable then shell builtins are the right approach. Do tell...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### With `awk`:

```
echo "206.195.152.176" | awk -F'.' '{print $3,$2,$1}' OFS='.'
```

#### With `sed`:

```
echo "206.195.152.176" |sed -r 's/([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3})/\3.\2.\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending how your IP address is stored and some other things unspecified in your question, this may be what you want:

```
$ var='206.195.152.176'
$ echo "${var:8:3}.${var:4:3}.${var:0:3}"
152.195.206
```

Comment: just check if the ${var:...} substitution is allowed on your shell (not on traditionnal KSH where ksh93 allow it like bash). Certainly the fastest and taking very low extra ressources (no forked pipe , ...)

Comment: The question is tagged with `bash` so this substitution is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this as folows

```
 echo "206.195.152.176"|sed -e 's#\([[:digit:]]\{3\}\).\([[:digit:]]\{3\}\).\([[:digit:]]\{3\}\).*#\3.\2.\1#'
```

Results

```
152.195.206
```